# How to make a second API call based on the first response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to call 2 APIs for displaying data on my component but the second api needs headers from the response of first API.
I am using React Hooks. I update the state from the first response so i can use it later for the second call, but it goes undefined. What am i doing wrong?

P.s a better way of doing this calls (maybe using async/await) would be much appriciated

```
 const [casesHeaderFields, setCasesHeaderFields] = useState([]);
 const [casesFields, setCasesFields] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      const result1 = axios
        .get(`firstUrl`)
        .then(response => {
         //I need this as headers for my second API
          setCasesHeaderFields(
            response.data.result.fields
          );
        });

      const result2 = axios
        .get(`url${casesHeaderFields} //here i want to pass params from 
         //first response)
        .then(response => {
          setCasesFields(response.data.result.record_set);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: chain your promises or use `async/await` and block execution of your `result2` call. what do you mean by `P.s a better way of doing this calls (maybe using async/await) would be much appriciated`? `async/ await ` is simple enough...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make the second call inside a .then chained to the end of the first promise chain ... in simple terms, chain your promises

Something like

```
useEffect(() => axios.get(`firstUrl`)
    .then(response => {
        setCasesHeaderFields(response.data.result.fields);
        return response.data.result.fields;
    })
    .then(casesHeaderFields => axios.get(`url${casesHeaderFields}`))
    .then(response => {
        setCasesFields(response.data.result.record_set);
    }), []);
```

Comment: sorry, this isn't quite tight ... bracket fail :p

Comment: fixed now - sorry about that

Comment: thank you. I am choosing this one as the answer as you made it totally ready for me :p Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I figured you still wanted to do the `setCasesHeaderFields` and `setCasesFields` stuff (even though I don't know what its doing :p )

Answer (score 10):

You can chain the results as they are regular promises:
[Ref](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/708)

```
axios.get(...)
  .then((response) => {
    return axios.get(...); // using response.data
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Response', response);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The queries `result1` and `result2` look sequential but there are simultaneous. In other words, `result2` doesn't wait for `result1` to finish before being executed.

Here is a working example to chain promises using async/await:

```
useEffect(async () => {
  try {
    // Make a first request
    const result1 = await axios.get(`firstUrl`);
    setCasesHeaderFields(result1.data.result.fields);

    // Use resutlt in the second request
    const result2 = await axios.get(`url${"some params from result1"}`);
    setCasesFields(result2.data.result.record_set);
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error here
  }
}, []);
```

EDIT

Based on comments, here is a best way to use async with useEffect without warning in the console:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // Make a first request
      const result1 = await axios.get(`firstUrl`);
      setCasesHeaderFields(result1.data.result.fields);

      // Use resutlt in the second request
      const result2 = await axios.get(`url${casesHeaderFields}`);
      setCasesFields(result2.data.result.record_set);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error here
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: axios.get(`url${"some params from result1"}`)? for example like result1.data.fields? or i pass the state caseHeaderFields?

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      return axios
        .get(`firstUrl`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.data.result.field
        }).then(result => { 
         return axios.get(`url${result}`)
        });
   });
```

With async / await :

```js
  useEffect(async () => {
      const result1 = await axios
        .get(`firstUrl`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.data.result.field
        });
      const result2 = await axios.get(`url${result1}`)
      return result2 
   });
```

Comment: You can notice with arrow function no need to use `return` just write for example `=> response.data.result.field`.

Comment: Not correct approach for using `async` with useEffect()

Comment: why because I didn't wrap my code with `try-catch` block ?

Comment: No , take a look at edit Baboo answer made for same issue which is correct approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` to relieve the mess.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`firstUrl`)
    const result = await axios.get(`url${response.data.result.fields}`)
    console.log(result.data)
})
```

Comment: You can't call a `useEffect` function `async`. At least React will throw a warning if you do.